# How to I confirm whether my GC issue is a memory leak or just not enough heap memory allocated?

Tags: java-8, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have an app running in java8 and Tomcat 8.5.  I'm running tests against it and I think there is a memory leak as if I run a series of POSTs (REST calls pushing data to a db) I get a 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded' error.  At the moment I am pretty much using all the defaults.  The posts I am doing are not enormous and I am leaving a 3 second gap between each post.

I noticed the default Tomcat JVM memory size is pretty small (126 on start with a max of 252).  When I connect using jconsole it shows 'PS Old Gen' as maxed out pretty much all the time, Survivor space not moving much and Eden space going up and down but hitting 99%/100% before the error arises.  If I use tomcat8w.exe to massively increase the memory to 2 GB the problem 'goes away'.

What I'm struggling to understand is how I work out whether there is a memory leak or whether it is just that the system needs more memory allocated?

If my error is caused by Eden Space hitting 100% does this mean that there is not a memory leak as this presumably means the objects were hanging about long enough to be moved up around the heap and it should be 'PS Old Gen' which is filling up, or is it that the JVM might be losing track of objects and so they fill up Eden Space and never get moved on ?

Comment: There is no general answer. But usually, when you get “GC overhead limit exceeded”, it’s not a memory leak but too little memory. That’s especially true if giving it significantly more memory solves the error, assuming you let it run long enough, i.e. until gc was triggered multiple times and the maximum memory consumption does not keep growing anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use tomcat8w.exe to massively increase the memory to 2 GB the problem 'goes away'.

Use this limit and keep monitoring the system for several days. If the old generation occupancy *after major collections* (i.e. the peak of the common see-saw pattern) levels out at some value then it's probably not a leak.
If the peak old gen occupancy keeps creeping up it's probably a leak.

Comment: Thanks.  It was a memory leak in some services I wasn't testing!